# How to install dashboard-nvim with vim-plug?

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug

How to install the dashboard-nvm plugin written in lua with vim-plug?

If I want to set some configurations, which file I should modify?

I am using `init.vim` and vim-plug has been installed. The version number of my neovim is 0.8.2.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you using `init.vim` or `init.lua`? Are you already using `vim_plug`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited my question.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `init.vim` you should

1. Have in your `init.vim` file:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'glepnir/dashboard-nvim'
call plug#end()
```

2. Restart Neovim
3. Run `:PlugInstall`
4. Restart Neovim

[image: Dashboard on Neovim]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If the solution address your problem I'll be glad if you could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It let the question rest :-)